# Cant install app from PlayStore for Android 12 targetSDK 31

Tags: android-sdk-2.3

Recently I have updated CompileSDKVERSION: 31,
User can download the app but after download, app is not getting install in android lastet version 12
Can't install app error is coming. Pleas someone help. I have mentioned the gradle file and in manifest mentioned exported:true

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mbanking.mpab.mpab"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 34
        versionName "4.1.6"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    bundle {
        language {
            // Specifies that the app bundle should not support
            // configuration APKs for language resources. These
            // resources are instead packaged with each base and
            // dynamic feature APK.
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
    buildTypes {/*  debuggable true*/
        release {

            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }


    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

ext {

    zxingVersion = '1.9.8'
    gsonVersion = '2.8.4'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    /* Default lib - for instrumentation testing support */
    /* Android support lib - default */
    /*   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'*/
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    /* DeviceInfo lib - for fetching all details about a device */
    implementation 'com.an.deviceinfo:deviceinfo:0.1.5'
    /* Retrofit - networking lib. Includes:
    * 1. gson lib - for serialisation
    * 2. rxJava lib
    * 3. okhttp interceptor lib - for intercepting network calls & logging response
    * 4. PersistentCookieJar - for cookie support
    * */

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1'

    implementation 'com.github.franmontiel:PersistentCookieJar:v1.0.1'
    /* Firebase - for notification support */
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    /* Picasso - Image Loading lib: for displaying qr codes */
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    /* Picasso - Image Loading lib: to add headers to the qrcode request */
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    /* zxing lib - for scanning qr codes */
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
    /* Rootbeer lib - for checking if device is rooted or not */
    implementation 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.0.6'
    /* Crashlytics lib for debugging crashes */
    /*   implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:17.2.2@aar') {transitive = true}*/
    /* Android Architecture Component - ConstraintLayout */
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    /* Android Architecture Component - LiveData & ViewModel */
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    /* Android Architecture Component - Navigation */
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0-rc02'
    /* Android Architecture Component - RxAndroid */
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
    /* Android Architecture Component - Paging Lib */
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.1.0'
    /* MpAndroidChart lib - for chart implementation */
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    /* JodaTime lib - for manipulating time/date */
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
    implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
    /* Mockito lib - for unit testing */
    /* Default lib - for junit test support */
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    /* Espresso lib - for instrumentation testing */
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'

    //old plugin
    /*storing prefereence value */
    implementation 'com.scottyab:secure-preferences-lib:0.1.7'

    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    //JSON Parsing
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.mancj:Slideup-Android:1.0-beta'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation files('libs/spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.release.jar')
    implementation files('libs/spring-android-core-1.0.1.release.jar')
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.2'
    implementation 'androidmads.library.qrgenearator:QRGenearator:1.0.3'

    // Zxing barcode dependency
    implementation "me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:$zxingVersion"
    implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.4.jar')
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'
    //login pin
    implementation 'com.poovam:pin-edittext-field:1.2.1'
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
    //for uatt
implementation files('libs\\aars\\Android-App-SDK-debug.aar')

}
```

Even I have updated the latest dependency for retrofit /app compact but its not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.